# Salesforce login

Tags: login

I have two  users with same salesforce license,for one user if i have given login credentials,the user has to view the classic page and if i login with another user credentials for login,the user has to view the lightining page,is there possible 
to give permission set for this scenario?if possible what permission i have to give inorder to acheive this?can anyone please help me for this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean you have two people sharing the same authentication details?

Answer (score 1):

See this page: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/lex_enable_users.htm

Specifically:

> Want to test Lightning Experience with a small group of users? Create a permission set that includes the Lightning Experience user permission. Then apply the permission set to each of your pilot users. When you turn on Lightning Experience, only these custom profile users see the new interface.

Comment: after entering credentials,login page should be lightining

Comment: If i have given permission lightning experience permission from system permission and add that permission set to particular user, but still it is not login to lightning page

Comment: May sound silly, but if you switch it for them it will default to that version for the future.  You can hide the ability to switch back too: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_general_lex_hide_switcher.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can enable lightning for each individual user.

[Enable Lightning for each user](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_introduction/units/lex_migration_introduction_administration)

Comment: please incldue the essential "How to's" in your answer, as links are bound to break, making your answer pretty much useless in that case